# Rewrite PDE (chain rule?)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have this PDE
\begin{align}
u(x,t)\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} &=u(x,t)\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x^2} \quad \iff \\
\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(u(x,t))^2&=u(x,t)\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x^2} 
\end{align}
How is the LHS rewritten?
Why is $u(x,t)\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} =\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(u(x,t))^2$?

I guess I can't factor the $\partial/\partial t$, so $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\big (u(x,t)u(x,t)\big )$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the Chain Rule.

$$
(f^2)'=2\,f\,f'.
$$